# Create a new colum based on a formula involving a lookup table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a lookup table like this :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 h H k K m M b B   + - ? 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2 2 3 3 6 6 9 9 0 0 0 0
```

build with this code

```
symbols <- c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "h", "H", "k", "K", "m", "M", "b", "B","", "+", "-", "?")
exp <- c(seq(0,9),2,2,3,3,6,6,9,9,0,0,0,0)
names(exp) <- symbols
```

doing `exp[["k]]` does return `3` of class `numeric`

I have a data.table `noaa` with contains 2 columns, one with a value, and one with an exponent code like "k", or 4.
This DT comes from this file : https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2

I want to create a new column `TOTALVALUE` in that data.table such as the value is (below is a formula in pseudo code)

```
noaa$TOTALVALUE = noaa$VALUE*10^exp[[noaa$EXPONENT]] in which noaa$EXPONENT value is matched using the exp matching table
```

I tried the following code

```
noaa$test <- with(noaa, PROPDMG*10^exp[[PROPDMGEXP]])
```

and i get

```
Error in exp[[PROPDMGEXP]] : 
       attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

if I remove one of the [], then it goes in infinite loop and crashes.

What is the best way to achieve this ? The other alternatives I came up with so far would be to build `exp` as a data frame and use match, or build a function and use lapply on it

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  What is `DT` or `noaa`?  By the way `[[` is used for selecting a single element.  For multiple entries, use `[` i.e. `as.vector(exp[c("1", "k")])` instead of `exp[[c("1", "k")]]`

Comment: The following would work for you `DT[, TOTALVALUE := VALUE*10^exp[EXPONENT]]`

Comment: I added the source of the data.table, but my question is on the approach : how to you add a new column on a data table that will be filled by a calculation involving a matching table ?

Comment: The second comment should help you in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apart from

```
noaa[, TOTALVALUE := VALUE * 10 ^ exp[EXPONENT]]
```

which worked well but is quite slow, the following approach worked, and is much faster.

Instead of building a named vector, I built a dataframe with 2 columns :

```
symbols <- c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "h", "H", "k", "K", "m", "M", "b", "B","", "+", "-", "?")
expValue <- c(seq(0,9),2,2,3,3,6,6,9,9,0,0,0,0)
expTable <- data.frame(symbols, expValue)
```

then I used match to find the value, and create the two columns I needed in the end

```
noaa[, PROPDGMGVALUE := PROPDMG * 10 ^ expTable[match(PROPDMGEXP, expTable$symbols),2]]
noaa[, PROPDGMGVALUE := CROPDMG * 10 ^ expTable[match(CROPDMGEXP, expTable$symbols),2]]
```

**Results over 900k lines, 8 columns DT**

```
system.time(noaa[, pouet :=  PROPDMG*10^expValue[PROPDMGEXP]])
   user  system elapsed 
   223.11    0.03  223.28 

system.time(noaa[, PROPDGMGVALUE := PROPDMG * 10 ^ expTable[match(PROPDMGEXP, expTable$symbols),2]])
    user  system elapsed 
    0.04    0.00    0.04
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `[[` for a vectorized select, but `[[` *always* selects only a single element. You can switch to `[` to solve the problem:

```
x = 1:3
names(x) = letters[1:3]
# x
# a b c 
# 1 2 3 

x[["a"]]
# [1] 1

x[[c("a", "c")]]
# Error in x[[c("a", "c")]] : 
#   attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex

x["a"]
# a
# 1

# x[c("a", "c")]
# a c 
# 1 3
```

As commenters pointed out, it is best practice to use `:=` to add columns to a data.table - using `<-` instead of `:=` will miss out on much of the `data.table` efficiency. Akrun's suggestion to use the line below is perfect:

```
noaa[, TOTALVALUE := VALUE * 10 ^ exp[EXPONENT]]
```